# How to replace dict key names in python nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to replace key names in dictionary. But i'm able to do for simple dict not for the complex/nested dict.

```
{
"Team": {
    "DataState": "A",
    "GID": "0021500038",
    "TID": "1610612758",
    "PTS": "103",
    "FBPTS": "8",
    "PTSIP": "46",
    "BgLd": "12",
    "TIMREM": "0",
    "TFLS": "7",
    "TeamLine": [{
        "DataState": "A",
        "GID": "0021500038",
        "TID": "1610612758",
        "PER": "1",
        "PTS": "31",
        "FLS": "5"
    }, {
        "DataState": "A",
        "GID": "0021500038",
        "TID": "1610612758",
        "PER": "14",
        "PTS": "0",
        "FLS": "0"
    }]
}}
```

I want to replce GID with CODE. So how I can do this?

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765897/how-to-assign-a-value-to-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty, given that `d` is your dict:

```
import ast
new_d = ast.literal_eval(str(d).replace("'GID':","'CODE':"))
```

- convert dict as string
- replace quoted values
- convert back string as dict using `literal_eval`

that's not very academic I admit, but it's super simple and doesn't care about the nesting.

Answer (score -1):

`nested_thing["Team"]["Teamline"][i]["GID"] = CODE` ought to be what you want, where `i` = 0 for the first GID and 1 for the second

(Added, there's also a `nested_thing["Team"]["GID"]` at the top )